# how to copy/duplicate all github remote branches from a repository

Tags: git, github

I have a old github repository https://github.com/oldRepository which has many remote branches

- master
- branch1
- branch2
- branch3

I want to copy or duplicate all these branches in one shot to the new github repository https://github.com/newRepository instead of duplicating/copying only one at a time. How Do I do this?

Comment: If either of the repositories is not in GitHub, then the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454345/2088872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a new empty repository in your GitHub profile.  GitHub then displays several options for populating this repository.  The last one is an importing option:

1. [image]

If you click on <kbd>import code</kbd>, you have the opportunity to give the url of your old git repository:

2. [image]

You then have to click on <kbd>Begin import</kbd> at the bottom of the screen.  GitHub will figure out that's a git repository and will make a perfect clone:

3. [image]

You can then check:  all your commits, branches, tags of your old repository will be available in the new repository.